# the group_by function in dplyr library does not work

Tags: r

```
b <- data %>%
       group_by(smoker) %>%
   summarise(meanfev=mean(fev),sd=sd(fev),count=n(),se=sd/sqrt(count))
b
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#smoker meanfev    sd count     se
#<fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#1 0         2.64 0.867   589 0.0357
#2 1         2.64 0.867    65 0.108 

fev <- data$fev
```

I hope to calculate the mean and sd in groups 0 and 1. But it seems it gives me the same mean which is the mean of the entire dataset. I remember it happens last time when I used another dataset. I don't know why it happens. It worked well before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as data <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(data)).  Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: you probably have `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr`. Please restart R and load only `dplyr` and try again else explicitly use `dplyr::summarise`.